Convert "about 400m" into American units
How would I say "about 400 meters" colloquially in American units?

About a quarter of a mile?
About fifteen hundred feet?

Or something else?
EDIT:
To give an example.
"To defuse a World War II bomb, everyone in a radius of about 400m needs to leave their homes."

Another option would be about 400 yards.

If it is the sprint, we'd say "He runs the four-forty".

@PaulTanenbaum Interesting. In the past, I had the impression that yards are used more frequently in Britain, and Americans usually stick to feet.

Some Americans would accept "about the length of four football fields".

@CanadianYankee OK, but then no other English speaker would have any idea what you meant.

400m = 437.44 yards, or 1312.34 ft, so "a quarter of a mile" or "440 yards" are remarkably accurate, less than 1% out.  On the other hand,1500 ft not so much.

@PeterJennings Why wouldn't other English speakers understand 'about four football fields'? Association and gridiron football fields are roughly the same length.

Yards are indeed commonly used in the US. An important example is American football, where feet are almost never used, whereas 10 yards is a distance that is central to the game, and the offensive team’s position is invariably described as “on the n yard line.”

You might be asking how to say this in American English, but there's no such thing as "American units".  They're called Imperial units.

It depends on context. In a horse race, furlongs may be used. American football, yards. Drag racing, miles.

@stangdon You are right, I wanted to ask how American people would usually say it in the units they usually use.

@stangdon You are wrong.  Try asking for an imperial pint of beer in a New York bar!

Use an online converter. stangdon is right: the formal term is imperial units. There is no other term.

@bradimus Possibly because they don't know that, or possibly because they aren't football fans and haven't a clue as to the size of the field. I'm not and I don't.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Lambie, the imperial foot and the US foot are the same length.  But other units differ.  The imperial pint is 20 fluid ounces.  The US Pint is 16 fluid ounces.  There are other differences (but they are minor).  "Imperial" refers to the units of the British Empire, The formal term for the units used in the British Empire.  The formal term is United States customary units"  which as wikipeida notes are "not to be confused with imperial units) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units

For the track measurement, "400m" remains "400m"; "400m dash" is the American term for the track and field event. The only exception to this is the 1600m (or 1500m) is sometimes colloquially called "the mile"

What's the usecase you're thinking about, specifically? Like, can you edit the question to give one or two specific scenarios you're curious about?

@JamesK There is no US foot. There are feet, they are same everywhere and it is an imperial measurement as opposed to metric. No other thing is mentioned.//

@JFabianMeier When you say US units or American units, it is understood that it means units used in US, which may differ from other regions. What do you mean by US units?
United States customary units form a system of measurement units commonly used in the United States and most U.S. territories, since being standardized and adopted in 1832. In US, they say miles per hour or miles per gallon for kms per hour or kms per liter

I added an example.

@JFabianMeier When you say US units or American units, it is understood that it means units used in US, which may differ from other regions. US units = United States customary units form a system of measurement units commonly used in the United States and most U.S. territories, since being standardized and adopted in 1832. In US, they say miles per hour or miles per gallon for kms per hour or kms per liter

Is this an English question or a mathematics one?

This is a question about distance in meters, versus, what is used in NA, which would be yards or feet. How can that have to do with all measurements (dry or liquid)? It does not.

After 60 years of listening, I was amazed to learn this very week that many people  see US American units not as Imperial, but as Customary.
Prolly more often than not, the two are equal but the 'Customary' idea does seem to account for differences in gallons and some other measures.

In North America, for this kind of distance, we'd use feet or yards.
Please note: That is not to say that meters aren't use in other contexts.
Any online converter will convert this to feet or yards, which are distance measurements used in NA in a context like this one.
Here's we'd probably use yards: about 450 yards.
OR
One could also say: about 1,300 feet. Less likely. A quarter mile, more likely.
One sees on the back of fire trucks: Stay back 200 feet.
This question is relatively easy to answer and does not require going all over the measurment map. [going over the x map: idiom]
The name for the category feet/yards is imperial measurement (which can apply to other measurements as well, invented by the British).
The name for the category meters, is the metric system (invented by the French, by the way).

I can tell from experience and the comments you have already gained that this is going to be a highly controversial question. Part of your question can only really attract opinion-based answers, and people have different opinions. But there's a decent learning point about the differing measurement systems lurking within your question. If readers focus on the opinion part, answers will likely be unfairly downvoted, but I'm not here for the points, I'm here to help, so here we go...
There's a common misconception that the US uses the imperial system while the UK exclusively uses metric. A British comedian who works exclusively in the USA often plays to this misconception with a joke that the Eminem movie '8 Mile' was rebranded as '12.8 Kilometres' for the UK audience. The fact is that while most European countries use kilometres for travel, every road sign in the UK features measurements in miles and always has done. Tachometers display miles as the predominant measure on UK vehicles, although kilometres are also marked in smaller numerals for driving on the continent. Beyond the road, British people tend to use an odd mix of imperial and metric measures - we teach metric measurements in schools, but we still buy milk and beer in pints, weigh ourselves in stones and measure our height in feet and inches.
This inconsistency in UK measurements is actually helpful to your question, I feel, because we learn to instinctively use one system or the other. If I was measuring a new curtain rail for my home, I'd definitely use metric which is more precise with millimetres and is almost certainly going to be used when I visit the store; meanwhile, if I were estimating a distance between two objects (such as when we were 'socially distancing' during the pandemic) I'd think in terms of feet.
In the context of your example - the distance people must travel away from a bomb - my instinct is to use the measurement most commonly associated with travel, which is miles. 400 metres is 0.248548 miles, which, rounded up, would most commonly be described as "a quarter of a mile". If someone were looking at a map to calculate the blast radius around a bomb site, the legend of the map would almost certainly be in miles or kilometres as maps are predominantly used for travel, and so again, the measurement in miles or fractions of a mile would be most helpful.
I don't think a distance in feet would be particularly helpful to someone trying to travel away from a bomb site. One might be able to judge a rough distance of, say, 200ft from a vehicle in front of them, but when travelling away from something it would be harder to know when you've travelled without a marker. Most people know how far things are from their homes - they likely know that it is a mile to the store, or 2 miles to the other side of town, and things like that will act as markers to estimate that you've travelled half that distance, or a quarter of it and so on. The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that miles is the right choice.

Thanks, I also remember this mixture between imperial and metric units from my time in Cambridge. It's like people feel in feet and calculate in cm.

Very small correction: in your third paragraph you used 'more accurate' when you meant 'more precise'. (As an aside, an American would use 16ths of an inch anyway, which gives approximately the same level of precision.)

@aantia thank you for that correction, I appreciate you helping make my answer better! Regarding your aside, there are of course approximately 25mm to an inch, so I stand by saying that millimetres are more precise than inches! :D

@JFabianMeier You're welcome, and that's a pretty good analogy. The Imperial system was 'officially' dropped in the UK in 1965, although we didn't decimalise our money until 1971, so there are still generations alive that were taught Imperial measurements. There are also later generations that learned from those ones, not so much at school, but perhaps 'on the job' in trades. So there is still a mix of the two systems used. Even though milk is sold in litres, we have unusual carton sizes such as 2.272L, because that equals 4 pints and we call them '4 pinters'.

I once ordered a large coffee at Southampton airport, not understanding how much 20 ounces of coffee are ...
